# How to make SIP calls from Perl and receive DTMF input?

Tags: linux, perl, monitoring, sip

In a commandline Perl Application running on Linux I need to make a phone call (SIP), play an audio file then wait for and receive DTMF input from the callee.

I can not run any GUI applications, so most Linux SIP clients are out of the competition.

At the moment I'm using pjsua, unfortunately this has some issues I'd like to avoid.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

Are there any fully-scriptable commandline SIP client for Linux?
Are there any sane librarys that could be used?

Comment: Have you tried sipP? probably this will work for you. http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend FreeSWITCH. It actually comes with a Perl API, so you can talk to a FreeSWITCH server from your Perl program and originate calls, send/receive DTMF, play audio files, etc.

There is also a way to let FreeSWITCH call your Perl program when a phone call arrives, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to implement your own SIP Client in Perl. This will be a PITA and waste of time, as there are ready-to-use implementations out there.

For example, you can use [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/asterisk) for this. With its scripting capabilities it is very flexible. It has a great community and is well documented - you find many examples in the web.

Other solutions comparable to Asterisk are [Yate](http://yate.null.ro) and [FreeSwitch](http://www.freeswitch.org).

In Asterisk, you would basically:

1. start a call by placing a [call file](http://www.the-asterisk-book.com/unstable/call-file.html) in a spool directory.
2. connect that new outgoing call to a special "extension" (which is a script block, basically):

Example dialplan script:

```
[specialstuff]
exten => s,1,Wait(1)                  ; wait a second before playback
exten => s,2,Playback(yourfile.wav)   ; play your file
exten => s,3,AGI(yourscript.pl)       ; run your script with AGI interface
       ; in "yourscript.pl" you can wait for / receive DTMF and react on it
```

Alternatively, you can implement the DTMF stuff completely in Asterisk. This is called an IVR (interactive voice response). There are many examples out in the web.

```
[specialstuff]
exten => s,1,Wait(1)                  ; wait a second before playback
exten => s,2,Playback(yourfile.wav)   ; play your file
exten => s,3,WaitExten(10)            ; wait 10 seconds for DTMF input

exten => 1,1,System(/your/script.pl one)   ; callee pressed DTMF 1
exten => 1,2,Playback(thanks)              ; give feedback

exten => 2,1,System(/your/script.pl two)   ; callee pressed DTMF 2
exten => 2,2,Playback(goodbye)             ; give feedback

exten => 3,1,System(/your/script.pl three) ; callee pressed DTMF 3
exten => 3,2,Playback(something)           ; give feedback
```

Comment: I neither like Asterisk nor the idea of using a PBX as a SIP client. However I must admit that this may be the best solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @tex dont want to convince you that asterisk is good .. just wanted to mention that asterisk actually is not a PBX. it is a framework. It is often used as a PBX. Just like Apache is not a webshop, but is often used to serve one.

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago I had a look at implementing a SIP client for something like this using the available CPAN modules.

However in the end I settled on using [SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/). It isn't completely intuitive (I spent a lot of time debugging callflows in Wireshark) but in the end it did everything that I needed to do and more.